# The reason why each person is not fully independently trained just because two objects are created in this tensorflow code

Tags: python, tensorflow

> model_SoftmaxNN_LC = class_SoftmaxNN() This part.
> model_SoftmaxNN_LC_A = class_SoftmaxNN() model_SoftmaxNN_LC_B =
> class_SoftmaxNN() If corrected, two objects, model_SoftmaxNN_LC_A and
> model_SoftmaxNN_LC_B, will be inherited from all one class attribute.

In the current Tensorflow code, creating these two objects will not completely independently learn each other. Why is that?
How do I modify the code so that each can be learned independently?

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
import torch.nn as nn

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
print(train_images.shape, train_labels.shape, test_images.shape, test_labels.shape)
train_images = train_images.reshape([-1,784]).astype('float32') / 255.0
test_images = test_images.reshape([-1,784]).astype('float32') / 255.0
train_labels = tf.one_hot(train_labels, depth=10)
test_labels = tf.one_hot(test_labels, depth=10)
batch_size = 1000
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images, train_labels))
train_data = train_data.repeat().shuffle(5000).batch(batch_size)

nH1 = 256
nH2 = 256
nH3 = 256

class class_SoftmaxNN_LC(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    self.W_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([784,nH1]))
    self.b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([nH1]))
    self.W_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([nH1,nH2]))
    self.b_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([nH2]))
    self.W_3 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([nH2,nH3]))
    self.b_3 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([nH3]))
    self.W_o = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([nH3,10]))
    self.b_o = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([10]))
  def __call__(self, x):
    H_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,self.W_1)+self.b_1)
    H_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(H_1,self.W_2)+self.b_2)
    H_3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(H_2,self.W_3)+self.b_3)
    Out = tf.matmul(H_3,self.W_o)+self.b_o
    return Out
  
model_SoftmaxNN_LC = class_SoftmaxNN_LC()
optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(0.01)

def cost_Softmax(x,y):
  return tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=x, labels=y))

def train_optimization(MNIST_images, MNIST_labels):
  with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    prediction = model_SoftmaxNN_LC(MNIST_images)
    cost = cost_Softmax(prediction, MNIST_labels)
  gradients = g.gradient(cost, vars(model_SoftmaxNN_LC).values())
  tf.optimizers.Adam(0.01).apply_gradients(zip(gradients, vars(model_SoftmaxNN_LC).values()))

for epoch in range(1,11):
  for step, (batch_images, batch_labels) in enumerate(train_data.take(60),1):
    train_optimization(batch_images, batch_labels)
    if step % 10 ==0:
      pred = tf.nn.softmax(model_SoftmaxNN_LC(batch_images))
      accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(pred, batch_labels), tf.float32))
      print('Epoch: {} \t Step: {}\t Accuracy: {}'.format(epoch,step,accuracy))

test_model = tf.nn.softmax(model_SoftmaxNN_LC(test_images))
test_accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(test_model, test_labels), tf.float32))
print('Test Accuracy:', test_accuracy.numpy())
```

Comment: "How do I modify the code so that each can be learned independently?" - rewrite this script without using that class....also what's the use of nH1 = 256
nH2 = 256
nH3 = 256 anyhow?

Comment: It was created separately to easily change the number of units in the Hidden Layer. Then, for example, tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([784,nH1]))) This part is tf.Variable (tf.random.normal ([784,256]))) Like this?